# Android linear gradient incorrectly fades in the middle?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a linear gradient defined as a drawable in xml with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<shape 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:type="linear"
      android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
      android:centerColor="@color/CenterColor"
      android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
      android:gradientRadius="100"
      android:centerX="0.5"/>
</shape>
```

CenterColor is defined as #E6E7E8.

My view is defined as:

```
<View
  android:id="@+id/addressGradientDivider"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/addressTextView"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/NormalVerticalMargin"
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/SmallHorizontalMargin"
  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/SmallHorizontalMargin"
  android:background="@drawable/DetailsGradientDivider"/>
```

The result is a gradient like the following:

[image]

For whatever reason the gradient is fading in the middle and I can't figure out why. I have also tried setting the gradient programmatically and got the same results.

**Why is the gradient fading in the middle and how can I get the darkest part of the gradient to be in the center?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is `@android:color/transparent` is #00000000 the transparent of black (#000000) and also your centerColor is very light gray. 
The center color that you see as fading is actually #E6E7E8.

So, if you blend this transparent of black and very light gray, you will see slightly darker gray in between when the alpha is not fully 00.

If you change the startColor to #00FFFFFF (transparent of white), you will not see the gray gradient at 25% and 75% position. Though, the centerColor is very close to white, so it is even hard to see the gradient.

Comment: AH! That was it! :D Good eye! Thank you!